# android libpcap -> no such file or directory

Tags: android, libpcap

I'm trying to use libpcap with android to test it I wrote a simple c program that looks like this

```
 #include <string.h>
 #include <pcap.h>
 #include <jni.h>

 jstring Java_com_example_penguin_AvailableHosts_stringFromJNI(JNIEnv* jobject thiz) {
     char *dev, errbuf[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];

     dev = pcap_lookupdev(errbuf);
     if (dev != NULL)
         return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, dev);
     else
         return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "ERROR");
}
```

The Android.mk file looks like

```
 LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
 include $(CLEAR_VARS)
 LOCAL_MODULE    := test
 LOCAL_SRC_FILES := test.c
 include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

In the root of my project I call

```
 ndk-build
```

which gives me the following error

```
 jni/test.c:2:18: fatal error: pcap.h: No such file or directory
 compilation terminated.
```

Is there anything missing in the Android.mk file?